# How to store one billion files on ext4?

Tags: linux, inode, ext4

I only created about 8 million files, then there was no free inode in /dev/sdb1.

```
[spider@localhost images]$ df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1            8483456 8483456       0  100% /home
```

Someone says can specify the inode count when format the partition.

e.g. mkfs.ext4 -N 1000000000.

I tried but got an error:

> "inode_size (256) * inodes_count (1000000000) too big...specify higher inode_ratio (-i) or lower inode count (-N). ".

What's the appropriate inode_ratio value?

I heard the min inode_ratio value is 1024 for ext4.

Is it possible to store one billion files on a single partition? How to? And someone says it will be very slow.

Comment: I don't think you can with `ext4`. But you might with [zfs](http://zfsonlinux.org/).

Comment: I didn't hear of zfs before, is it easy to use?

Comment: It's a file system. It has a lot of features.

Comment: The smallest file system block size allowed is usually 1024 bytes (1k). The smallest bytes per inode you can specify is as small as the the file system block size. Specifying a smaller then file system block will create more inodes that can ever be used. With file system block size at 1k and bytes per inode at 1k, a 1 TB disk will almost have 1 billion inodes.

Comment: However, I would avoid having many million files in the same directory.... So use a  `/data/dir012/subdir234/file4567.txt` naming scheme...

Comment: Consider also, especially if each file is small (less than 8Kbytes) using a database (MariaDB, PostGresql, MongoDb, ...) or `sqlite` or `gdbm`

Comment: @ElliotFrisch: recent Ext4, at least suitably configured & tuned, are expected to be able to hold many billions of files in a file system.

Comment: @alvits What's the appropriate file system block size? Is 1k too small? How did you figure out that "With file system block size at 1k and bytes per inode at 1k, a 1 TB disk will almost have 1 billion inodes."?

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch Why use "/data/dir012/subdir234/file4567.txt"?

Comment: @redice: you want to avoid huge directories. Limit the number of directory entries to a few thousands.

Comment: @redice - `Total size / block size = total number of blocks`. For an `inode` to be used, it must not be more than the number of blocks. If total size = 1TB and block size = 1KB, then 1TB / 1KB = 1 billion blocks. Here's why you can't have more inodes than blocks. If you have a file system that can hold 1 million blocks and you forced it to have 2 million blocks, what will happen after you saved 1 million files (assuming files are equal to or smaller than block size), you will run out of blocks (space). If you have more blocks than inode (typical), you will run out of inodes if files are small

Comment: **What is the use case?** What are these billion files containing? (images, textual data, ...?)? Why don't you consider other data storage techniques (databases, indexed files à la GDBM, ...)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch All are images. I just afraid the database is slow than file system.

Comment: You should not care: your problem is I/O bound not CPU bound, so the few 0.01% added by a database is completely noise.

Comment: in addition to zfs, btrfs and xfs don't suffer with inode issues. I tend to prefer btrfs

Comment: also see [EXT4 “No space left on device (28)” incorrect](https://serverfault.com/q/384541/343888)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When creating an ext4 file system, you can specify the usage type:

```
mkfs.ext4 -T usage-type /dev/something
```

The available usage types are listed in /etc/mke2fs.conf. The
main difference between usage types is the inode ratio. The lower
the *inode ratio*, the more you can create files in your file
system.

The usage type in mke2fs.conf which allocates the highest number of
inodes in the file system is "news". With this usage type on a 1
TB hard drive, ext4 creates 244 million inodes.

```
# tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1 | grep -i "inode count"
Inode count:              244219904
# sgdisk --print /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
```

This means that it would require more than 4 TB to create an ext4
file system with "-Tnews" that could possibly hold 1 billion
inodes.

Comment: Will it be slow if creating so many inodes?

Comment: Yes, it will take a very long time. For instance, on my deskop machine, 14 seconds are needed to create 10000 files in a single directory and more than 2 minutes to create 100000 files, so creating 1 billion files probably requires days or weeks.

Comment: btrfs has no problems creating 1 billion files. creating 100,000 files takes 3 seconds ON MY LAPTOP with btrfs

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(){
char buf[10+1];//need 11 for the terminating NULL character of 1 billion. 
for(uint_fast32_t i=0;i<100000;++i){
sprintf(buf,"%i",i);
close(open(buf,O_CREAT));
}
}
```

Comment: - and that's a single-threaded approach. try multithreading that

Comment: adding -O3 (max optimize) to gcc, turned it down to:
```real 0m1.876s
user 0m0.020s
sys 0m1.808s
```

tl;dr: it takes <2 seconds to create 100,000 files on my laptop with btrfs. lel