# How to Increase inode limits on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, inode

I'm setting up a server on linode.com. I have 48G ssd. I put a lot of small files. The system is showing me a message saying No spece left, but by using df -h command, I see I still have 19GB unused. Then I used df -i and found that no inode is available anymore. The total number of inode is 3056000. How can I increase this limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO you can not change the inode limit after creating the filesystem for many filesystems. 
You can set the number of inodes by using the `-N` switch of `mkfs`. Before recreating the filesystem you can check the default calculation of inodes by using the `-n` switch.
consult this answer: [How to store one billion files on ext4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21397110/how-to-store-one-billion-files-on-ext4) for more information.